# Can an object become 'stuck' inside another object (because its deep)?

Tags: javascript, object

> This question is not specific to this particular scenario. The scenario could be concerning any complex/deep JavaScript object but for me to visualize the question I need a scene. Do not answer specifically on the supplied example - only cloning, scope and objects.

### Brief Outline

If I have stored a [websocket](https://github.com/websockets/ws) object inside an object, could I later move this websocket out of the storage object and put into another object? kind of like when you pop or splice an array, the array item is not only removed from the array but it's also returned to you (not obliterated but transferred / 'plucked from'). Or is the websocket object stuck/tied to the storage object `{}`? (If so, in what state would the object ***be*** in a lower scope?? What is it 'then'?)

Obviously:

```
//pseudo code

var finalobject = Object.assign({},storageobject.socket);
//not in nodejs? probably a bad idea anyway

var finalobject = storageobject.socket;
//only a shallow reference

delete storageobject.socket

finalobject.test = 'abc123';
// Obvious TypeError: Cannot set property..bla bla
```

what would I have though if?:

```
function lowerscope(x){return x;}

var sameobject=lowerscope(storageobject.socket);
```

is `sameobject` now dolly the sheep? a shallow reference or a deep reference? a copy?

### **My Question And The reason Why I think it's not a stupid question**

If I first assign the socket in the storage object to the `finalobject`
then delete the `storageobject.socket` then I cant use the `finalobect` or set properties because that was just a shallow reference to what I just deleted.

So what exactly is going on if I pass the `finalobject` through a function like so? (again pseudo code)

```
var finalobject = storageobject.socket;

function appInit(mySocket) {

    // do app stuff here with mySocket
    // set up some functions...

    return; // * come back out to main scope
    }

appInit(finalobject);

delete storageobject.socket; // * what am I deleting??
```

Is the object cloned into appInit? Or does it live there as just another reference?

### **Example of my code flow (optional; you can skip this):**

> This part is (too) specific to my case and is here only in case someone asks to see code or 'needs' to understand why I ask.

I have *put/created-reference-to* my newly created (node.js [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)) Websocket in another object:

```
var uid = '7657rrfdt6e6t'; //unique id

var socketsReference = {}; //main scope

socketServer.on('connection',function(mainSocket) {

    var socketsGroup = {}; //local scope

    mainSocket.uid = uid;

    socketsGroup[1] = mainSocket;

    socketsReference[uid] = socketsGroup;

    socketsGroup[1].send('uid:' + uid);
```

So that is the main socket that is stored in the object. It has just sent its uid to the client so that it can set that as its uid property too.

Then next thing I do is connect the client to a secondary socket. For this I want the secondary socket to end up with the similar `uid+'.s2'` unique id as the main so what I do is connect the second socket then send the new 2nd connection a message from the client to the server which tells the server side socket the uid of the mainSocket

```
secondarySocket.on('message', function(data) {

    this.uid = data.uid + '.s2';

    socketsReference[data.uid][2] = this;
```

Later in the application I take the correct user specific socket group and inject it into the main application where the connected user is in his own scope.

```
var mySockets = socketsReference[my_uid]

appInit(mySockets);
```

Comment: Are you asking how objects work in JS?

Comment: Objects are represented as references, just like in Java, Python and PHP. Simple test: `var foo = {}; function bar(xyz) { xyz.abc = 42; } console.log(foo.abc);`

Comment: Deep/complex objects rather than just plain objects